# how to get display monitors in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am still learning JavaFX. I decided to build quite a number of applications and now I'm building a projection software. A software that  changes display modes and get display screens. The problem here is:

1. How to get other display screens.
2. How to write the code which will switch the display mode.

I have been battling this for a while. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which APIs have you tried to use so far?

Comment: You can start here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269377/javafx-full-screen-on-second-screen

Comment: Does [`Screen.getScreens()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getScreens()) not work?

Comment: i do not have any idea of the appropriate api to use here. i'd b glad if u suggest one. and lastly i would test the Screen class to see if it matches what i want. thanks really appreciate